# Object.keys behaving as though parse result is a string

Tags: javascript, object

When I'm typing commands one at a time in my console, I get these results:

```
content = "{ \"hello\":\"world\" }"
'{ "hello":"world" }'

JSON.parse(content)
{hello: 'world'}

Object.keys(JSON.parse(content))
['hello']
```

This is the desired result, because I'm trying to .forEach the keys.  However, in my React app, I'm trying to use this code:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/appointments/24/goal_notes/1.json`).then((response) => {
      const content = response?.data?.content
      console.log(content);
      console.log(JSON.parse(content));
      console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(content)));
      // setAppointmentNoteContent(response?.data?.content);
    });
  }, []);
```

But I'm getting this result:

```
"{ \"hello\":\"world\" }"
{ "hello":"world" }
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18']
```

So it's like the third log is treating the object as a string, even though it was parsed.

Is this possibly because, in the React app, the value of content is coming from a .json column from my Rails backend?

How can I access the keys and values of this object?

Comment: Can you please edit this inot a stack snippet w/ the full code to replicate the issue?

Comment: I edited to add the full useEffect function.  I haven't worked with stack snippets before, so I'll probably need to work with that a bit before I can post one.

Comment: Good thinking, @cmgchess.  Yes it is.  What can I do about that?

Comment: try if you could JSON.parse twice

Comment: That did the trick!  If you want to write this as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Hao Wu's answer addresses this in detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the output, your `content` might be a string literal of a JSON string of a JSON string (somehow got `JSON.stringify`ed twice).

Make sure your JSON string is `{ "hello":"world" }`(length: 19) but not `"{ \"hello\":\"world\" }"`(length: 25), in that case you need to `JSON.parse` it twice to get the correct output, but you should be focused on how did you get that string in the first place (e.g. avoid using `JSON.stringify` on a string, fix malformed JSON file, using correct `Content-Type` on a JSON request: `application/json` etc.)

```js
let content = "{ \"hello\":\"world\" }"

console.log("length", content.length);
console.log(content);
console.log(JSON.parse(content));
console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(content)));
```

```js
let content = '"{ \\"hello\\":\\"world\\" }"';

console.log('length', content.length);
console.log(content);
console.log(JSON.parse(content));
console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(content)));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry that I can't comment because my reputation is not enough.

The attached code is different from the actual code, or the environment seems strange.

That code works as expected.

```js
  const content = "{ \"hello\":\"world\" }"
  console.log(content)
  console.log(JSON.parse(content))
  console.log(Object.keys(JSON.parse(content)))

  console.log(Object.keys(content))
```

my guess is your code uses `content` not `JSON.parse(content)`